# How to answer matrices problems involving "meet" and "join"?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

**Problem:** Given the matrix below find the **meet** and **join** of A and B.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1    & 0  & 1 \\
    1    & 1  & 0 \\  
    0    & 0  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
    0    & 1  & 1 \\
    1    & 0  & 1 \\  
    1    & 0  & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

How to answer this kind of questions? I have learned the basics to advance math and know how to answer matrices involving problems, but I am new to this "meet" and "join" type of questions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So this type of problems involves programming for it be solved?

Comment: @Jayce no, not at all. See answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just the pointwise meet and join of each entry. So the $(0,0)$ entry (top left) is $1  = 0 \lor 1$ for the join-matrix and $0 \land 1 = 0$ for the meet-matrix. The $(2,2)$ entry of the meet is $1 \lor1= 1$ and of the join $1 \land 1 = 1$.

In formulae:

$$(A \land B)_{ij} = a_{ij} \land b_{ij}$$

and

$$(A \lor B)_{ij} = a_{ij} \lor b_{ij}$$

So for this case the join is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and the meet is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Sorry, if I seem rude, I kinda don't get the steps on how to get the "join" and "meet". From what I notice though, in matrices A and B, their respective element at (row-column): 2-1, 1-3 and 3-3, both has 1 in which they are retained as 1 at the resulted "join" matrix whereas the other became zero.

Comment: ∨ is for join while ∧ is for meet? I'm willing to learn step by step if you don't mind. From the 2 given matrix, at A, its element at position 1-1 is 1 whereas on matrix B the element on 1-1 is 0. With that what should I realize or do? So I can know what to do with the other elements.

Comment: @Jayce yes to the symbols. The meet of $0$ and $1$ or $0$ and $0$ and $0$ is $0$ while the only way to get a meet of $1$ is when both are $1$. The only way to  get a join of $0$ is when both are $0$, otherwise it's $1$. etc. It's logocal and and or respectively.

Comment: You can use the elementwise/Hadamard product ($\odot$) to define both of these operations $$\eqalign{A\land B&=A\odot B\cr A\lor B&=(A+B-A\odot B)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Join two matrix is $1$ if both corresponding elements in two matrix is $1$. Otherwise $0$.

Meet of two boolean matrix is $1$ if either of corresponding element is $1$ and $0$ if both element is $0$.